# Mono says int is List<dynamic>

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, mono

I've been struggling to convert a .NET code to Mono. Everything works fine except this part:

[image]

As you see, `value` is int. Mono says that int is `List<dynamic>` (look at the value of `b`). The if statement then goes to the else if part and then throws an exception on line 129, because int cannot be casted to List. In .NET the else if part is correctly evaluated as false. Can anyone help, please?

Here's a copyable code :)

```
public static StringBuilder JsonValueToString(dynamic value, StringBuilder sb)
{
    if (value is JsonObject)
    {
        return value.BuildString(sb);
    }
    else if (value is List<dynamic>)
    {
        var xs = (List<dynamic>) value;
        sb.Append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < xs.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (i > 0) sb.Append(", ");
            JsonValueToString(xs[i], sb);
        }
        sb.Append("]");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(value.ToString());
        sb.Append(" ");
    }
    return sb;
}
```

// EDIT: Added a better picture.

// EDIT2: Added a code snippet.

Comment: What version of Mono are you targeting?

Comment: @HighCore Mono 3.2.8.

Comment: out of interest does `value as List<dynamic>` work as expected?

Comment: Simple fix for now: Replace `List<dynamic>` with `IList`

Comment: `value as List<dynamic>` just leaves the `xs` variable set to null, then it fails in the `for` loop.

Comment: If I replace it with `IList` the condition is still evaluated as true. :( I'm starting to fear that this might be a bug in Mono.

Comment: @Filip does it work if you replace `dynamic value` with `object value` in the function parameters (while keeping `IList`)?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That actually does seem to work! What is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Well, `dynamic` is not needed for what you were trying to do anyway... I just suggested to replace it with simple casting. But I guess you just found a bug in Mono as your initial approach should have worked in the first place.

Comment: If you are willing to make it an answer, I'll gladly accept it. :)

Comment: That's not an answer but a workaround, the *real* issue here is that `int is List<dynamic>`, and I have no clue why it behaves that way. I think it's a bug.

Comment: I'll try to point someone at Mono to this question.

Comment: I'm testing it out with Xamarin Studio 5.5 and it works just fine. Changing project settings to build with Mono/.NET 4.5 and Mono/.NET 4.0 still works fine.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using MonoDevelop 4.0.12 with Mono / .NET 4.0 set as target.

Comment: Further in the code it also tells me that `List` is `string`. There must be something wrong with my installation.

Comment: And again the problem seems to be lying in `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel out of curiosity, which version of Mono do you use? Mine is 3.2.8.

Comment: just tried it - works here (Mono 3.2.8, C# 4.0.0.0, Monodevelop 5.7)

Comment: Update to Mono 3.10 solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Mono 3.2.8. Update to Mono 3.10 solved the issue.